# am I still able to set sessions?

Tags: php

When I want to set a session I do;

`$_SESSION['name'] = "value";`

But when I am looking at my session_storage, it is empty!

Is there something wrong with php?

For the one who wants to see:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = "value";
?>
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help

Comment: @MehdiBounya the whole code is irrelevant!

Comment: @ChickenWing1996 no, no it isn't - you're not showing if you've started any sessions with `session_start()`

Comment: @ChickenWing1996 how so?

Comment: Even when I Only will do `$_SESSION['name'] = "value";` it should work

Comment: I wanted to see if you started a session, and if there is anything wrong with your code (typos)

Comment: @MehdiBounya ill update it for you!

Comment: can you `var_dump($_SESSION)` after setting the value

Comment: @MehdiBounya see the answer of Morgan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> session_storage

is completely diffrent by global

> $_SESSION

try with `var_dump($_SESSION);`

**SessionStorage** and **LocalStorage** allows to save key/value pairs in a web browser. a.k.a web storage.

`$_SESSION` is superglobal variable in PHP, read more here: [click](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: How is this? Before I did saw the session in my session_storage

Comment: can you please explain your answer?

Comment: Did you understand it, do not worry about asking

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. But it was a long time ago for me I used sessions, and when I did use it. It was in the storage

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you implement `session_start()` before setting the session. Then `var_dump($_SESSION)` to output your session values.